# Clicking a notification in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications, android-viewpager

I have an application with a service running . The service sends out notification based on time (say at 11 hours it sends a notification and at 11:30 hours, it sends another)

When the user clicks the notification I have to display a pop up (Dialog class in Android) in the application.

My Solution is : I start the MainActivity of my application when the user clicks on the notification and then show the Dialog.

The Problem: The Click takes the user to the first screen of the application. If the user is in some other screen  while the notification was clicked (I use a view pager in my application), I want the Dialog to be displayed on the screen currently the user is in and not on the first screen

How do I solve this issue ? Thanks for your solutions.

Comment: Then set `Page Position` to `Pending Intent` in `Notification` and get this value at your `mainActivity` and load page as per that position in your `View Pager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is create a static reference to the current Activity on your Application class ( example about how create an application class: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/ )

Having your Application class you should create an static Context like :

```
public static FragmentActivity currentActivity;
```

and now, you should populate this instance on each Activity.onCreate that you have.

After that, you can use this static Context to create your dialogs.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

For the dialog to be displayed on the same screen that the user is on, it'l best suite you to introduce a Theme.Dialog themed activity, add it with a pending intent to you Notification builder. Like:

```
    // This sets the pending intent that should be fired when the user clicks the
    // notification. Clicking the notification launches a new activity.
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourDialogActivity.class);
        //set flags according to your implementation
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
//       startActivity(intent);

            // Because clicking the notification launches a new ("special") activity, 
            // there's no need to create an artificial back stack.
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                     PendingIntent.getActivity(
                     this,
                     0,
                     intent,
                   PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT //also check the flags here
            );
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Builds the notification and issues it.
        mNotifyMgr.notify(integerHere, mBuilder.build());
```

In you manifest, add your activity with the theme dialog:

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.package.YourDialogActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

For detailed implementation, refer: [Define the Notification's Action](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#action)

This way, you won't call the MainActivity of your application and the DialogActivity will just open the app and show the dialog on the activity that was last open when app was minimized.

Comment: Thanks for the solution,it solves the problem i mentioned in my question,                                                             I also need to handle the case where,  When the user clicks the notification and if the application is not already running, I have to show the dialog with the main activity in the background (i.e Launch the application and then show the Dialog). Can you tell me How I can handle that case              ?

Comment: You are welcome, pls upvote/accept answers accordingly. You need to check if app status in the service, if the app is not running then it will be necessary to start your app, so can just pass a flag/value in intent while launching the main activity and check the value of that intent in onCreate or onResume, consequently show the dialog..i think your current implementation would help you there. you can put that in an if-else